# How to correctly add Maven dependency from mvnrepository

Tags: java, maven, twitter, dependencies

I'm having an issue adding a maven dependency, it's for a Twitter API dependency but I'll try and keep the question as generic as possible.

The dependency is located onthe maven site [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter.sdk.android/twitter/3.1.1)

It states that the repo is here:

```
Note: this artifact it located at Spring Plugins repository (http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/)
```

So I have created a pom with the specified dependency and repo:

```html
   <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven_twitter</id>
      <name>twitter</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.twitter.sdk.android</groupId>
     <artifactId>twitter</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

The repository ID and Name weren't given so I've given them a suitable name - is this wrong?

The error received is:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project java: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project.java:java:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:jar:3.1.1, com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:jar:3.1.1, com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:jar:3.1.1, com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:jar:3.1.1, com.android.support:support-v4:jar:23.1.1, com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:jar:23.1.1: Could not find artifact com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:jar:3.1.1 in maven_twitter (http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/) -> [Help 1]

**So my question is: is simply adding the repo and dependency details of the Maven site enough? Am I missing something?**

Comment: Perhaps, If you ran build before adding those dependencies you may need to go to your .m2/repository directory and delete existing com.twitter.sdk directory (or more precise each 3.1.1 directories for missing artifacts), maybe com.android.support too... then run `clean install` maven build. You must see in the console/log, how Maven tries to download missing artifacts from http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/ url and was it successful or not...

Comment: The location you have given where the twitter.sdk should be located is simply not true..cause mvnrepository is a search engine but not a usable maven repository. you need to find by reading the docs in which Maven repository the twitter.skd is available from....Furthermore cause it's contained in the http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/ but there is only a `aar` file available..which is not a `jar`....This can seen by the error message which states it can not find a `:jar`...